# unhandled microsoft .net framework exception in w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, .net, workflowservice

I am writing a console application which uses a workflow service. 
I tried to attach the visual studio to IIS process to debug my application in two visual studio console but it didn't work and after that when I try to do something with my service ( update the service, build the service, open the service in browser and etc) just in-time debugger pops up:
An unhandled Microsoft .net framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe[every time diffident number here]

P.S. I have a running service in IIS and before changing setup I didn't have any problem but now even after restarting I still have this problem.

Comment: If its killing the process then it is probably a stack overflow or some bug in unsafe code.  What appears in the windows event log?

Comment: it doesn't kill the process. I haven't change the code but I've change the setting and then error came up . in windows log, it is about callback exception. and it says something about the faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe and this is exactly the same service that I've tried to attach visual studio to it.

Comment: OK from your description I assumed the process was crashing.

Comment: Maybe give it a try with IIS express?

Comment: it was the IIS problem, I just solved it by restarting the server.

Comment: Also, I've removed the service and added it again

Answer (score 1):

Restart site in IIS and also restart app pool worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below article for more information. I solved this issue by running visual studio as Administrator.

http://anishantha87.blogspot.com/2014/09/an-unhandled-microsoft-net-framework.html

Hope this will help!